# Realm closes itself

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I use one static global Realm instance(never closed) on Application object only for use in UI Thread,

```
@UiThread
public static Realm getRealm() {
    if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
        return realmInstance;
    } else {
        Timber.e("Illegal access to getRealmObservable");
        throw new IllegalStateException("Only UI Thread can access this realm");
    }
}
```

and another single use realm for WorkerThread as following:

```
@WorkerThread
public static void executeOnSingleUseRealm(final Realm.Transaction transaction) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
        Timber.e("Wrong thread for Realm");
        throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong thread for Single use Realm");
    }

    Realm realm = null;
    try {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(transaction);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Exception in Single Use Realm transaction");
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

However I still see crashes on use of single global Realm instance: `This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.`

I don't know how it is even possible.

Here is how I initialise Realm instance:

Application onCreate

```
void onCreate(){
    ....
        Observable
            .fromCallable(() -> {
                Realm.init(SVApplication.this);
                RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                        .build();
                Realm.compactRealm(realmConfiguration);
                Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
                return true;
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((v) -> onRealmLoaded());
    }
}

void onRealmLoaded(){
    realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    ....
}
```

Here is one of the crashes from one of the activities:

```
void onStart(){
    ....    subscribeUntilDetach(realmInstance.where(Notification.class).findAllAsync().asObservable()
                        .onBackpressureLatest()
                        .switchIfEmpty(emptyNotification())
                        .map(notifications -> notifications.where().isNull("readTime").or().isEmpty("readTime").count())
                        .onBackpressureLatest()
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(count -> {
                            if (count == 0L) {
                                mNotificationBadge.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            } else {
                                mNotificationBadge.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", count));
                                mNotificationBadge.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }, throwable -> Timber.e(throwable, "Error setting notification count")));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        mCompositeSubscription.clear();
    }
}

protected void subscribeUntilDetach(@NonNull Subscription subscription) {
    mCompositeSubscription.add(subscription);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mCompositeSubscription.hasSubscriptions()) {
        mCompositeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

on some activities this line also crashes with same error:

`mCompositeSubscription.unsubscribe();`

Here is a stacktrace from Crashlytics, may not be fully accurate.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp.mobile/com.teknoloji.myapp.ui.pages.HomeActivity}: rx.b.f: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1443)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
Caused by rx.b.f: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
   at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(Unknown Source)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(Unknown Source)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(Unknown Source)
   at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.propagate(Unknown Source)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.next(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.accept(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitFirst(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject$1.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject$1.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Observable.create(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeCreate(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Observable.create(Unknown Source)
   at com.teknoloji.myapp.ui.pages.HomeActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1288)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6279)
   at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6325)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6330)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1443)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.
   at io.realm.BaseRealm.checkIfValid(Unknown Source)
   at io.realm.Realm.init(Unknown Source)
   at com.teknoloji.myapp.ui.pages.HomeActivity.lambda$onStart$3(Unknown Source)
   at com.teknoloji.myapp.ui.pages.HomeActivity$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.next(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.accept(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitNext(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager$SubjectObserver.emitFirst(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject$1.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.BehaviorSubject$1.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.subjects.SubjectSubscriptionManager.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Observable.create(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeCreate(Unknown Source)
   at rx.Observable.create(Unknown Source)
   at com.teknoloji.myapp.ui.pages.HomeActivity.onStart(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1288)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6279)
   at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6325)
   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6330)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3336)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3384)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1443)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: Are you calling `realm.close()` elsewhere in your project?

Comment: @Fondesa No, this is the only place where I close realm (and I only close for WorkerThread). Errors are happening on UI Realm.

Comment: Are you using `executeOnSingleUseRealm()` only on a not-UI thread? The annotation `@WorkerThread` is only used by hint, it doesn't force another thread usage.

Comment: I check current Thread by `Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()`. If it is UI thread, it should throw my exception.

Comment: Right, my bad. Can you post here the code used to initialize the shared instance for the UI-thread Realm?

Comment: Everytime you call executeOnSingleUseRealm this method, the finally block will be called and your connection will be closed.

Comment: @HansWurst, this is why it is called `SingleUse`. and it only creates/closes realm in background thread. it does not touch UI instance of Realm.

Comment: It sure looks like executeOnSingleUseRealm would be invoked one time too much. From where will the method be invoked? Could you place a log messages into executeOnSingleUseRealm for debugging?

Comment: @HansWurst, `executeOnSingleUseRealm` is used only after Login. then application never uses it. on relaunches, login is not required. Logging will be pointless, it is not reproducible on dev. environments. and on Production it is reported already.

Comment: Stack trace pls, kinda hard to tell what doesn't work if I don't have the class and the line where it crashes

Comment: Can I ask for the apk file to check? the below code will close realm1 but i am not sure if it is your case: `Realm realm1 = Realm.getInstance(); Realm realm2 = Realm.getInstance(); realm2.close(); realm2.close();`

Comment: @beender, my code has 3 .close calls (register/login/forget password). and I checked on firebase crash reporting most of the crashes happens without any of those calls. (_login is 1 time in app usage_)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is:

> A closed exception indicates that you're attempting to use a closed
>   realm, utilizing Realm in a way that would not be promoted as the best
>   practice. ... Each activity is supposed to have its own realm instance
>   for best performance. ... create a realm instance at onCreate() and
>   destroy the instance at onDestory().
>   https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2594#issuecomment-211793848

Furthermore

> ...it is not a good idea that keep a static field of Realm in the class. It is recommended to control the Realm's life cycle within the Activity/Fragment/etc https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Because creating new instances in Realm, when there is at least one open, is super fast, don't be afraid to create multiple instances of Realm.

A senior software engineer from Realm points that out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429292/is-closing-and-reopening-realm-instances-bad-for-performance):

> As long as you have at least one instance open on a thread calling Realm.getInstance() it is just a HashMap lookup... Best practise is to keep the Realm instance open for as long as your thread lives.

The best practice is described in the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances):

```
// Setup Realm in your Application
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Realm.init(this);
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
}

// onCreate()/onDestroy() overlap when switching between activities.
// Activity2.onCreate() will be called before Activity1.onDestroy()
// so the call to getDefaultInstance in Activity2 will be fast.
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

For worker threads the [documentation recommends](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances) to get a new instance of Realm at the beginning and close it at the end.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    try {
        // ... Use the Realm instance ...
    } finally {
        realm.close();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have read documentation.
I did not wanted to follow this approach because first initialisation takes time. and I put it in background thread.

Since initialisation in background is taking some time, `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` on `onCreate ` is also failing.

I have also read from another senior engineer keeping one static final Realm for UI thread is also fine. Something is not right, but my implementation is just revealing it.

Comment: Yes the first initialisation takes a short time, but it's only done when you start the app. I would follow the guidelines of realm, because even if you get it working, there could be other problems in the future.

Comment: I think the problem is, that you init Realm in a worker thread. After the initialisation is finished you set the `realmInstance`. You're accessing the `realmInstance` in `onStart` and this can happen before `realmInstance` is initialised. Does the problem still happen when you init the `realmInstance` normal on the mainthread?

Comment: The problem is, I am not closing realm. but it closes itself. same could happen if route cause is not fixed.

Comment: No it is not, but I would love to avoid initing on Main Thread.

Comment: So if you still can init the first realm instance on a background thread and save it in the Application, as you have it already with the `realmInstance`, but you need to get a fresh instance for each Fragment and Activity, which is super fast, if you already have at least one instance of realm.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is around `RealmObservableFactory`. I have removed all `Rx` + `Realm` relations (`.asObservable()` etc.), used old school implementation and it went well.